# Angularjs: missing dependency

Tags: angularjs

When I launch my angularjs application I am getting this error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'App' is not available! You
either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering
a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
argument. http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$injector/nomod?p0=App
```

As I have about 20 dependencies. How can I know which dependency is not satisfied?

```
angular.module('myApp', ['LocalStorageModule', 'tmh.dynamicLocale','ngResource', 'ui.router',   
'ngCookies','pascalprecht.translate', 'ngCacheBuster', 'ngTable',   
'ngSanitize','ui.select','angularValidator','ui.bootstrap','googlechart',   
'ui.bootstrap.showErrors','ngActivityIndicator','ncy-angular-breadcrumb',
'anguFixedHeaderTable', 'ui.utils','io.dennis.contextmenu'])
```

Comment: share your angular.module statement?

Comment: trace it even if its 20, dont be lazy

Comment: how? by removing them one by one et relaunch the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular is trying to load a module called `app`. As your code looks like, you define your module name as `myApp` - so just rename one of them to archieve name equality.

EG:

```
angular.module('app', ['LocalStorageModule', 'tmh.dynamicLocale','ngResource', 'ui.router',   
'ngCookies','pascalprecht.translate', 'ngCacheBuster', 'ngTable',   
'ngSanitize','ui.select','angularValidator','ui.bootstrap','googlechart',   
'ui.bootstrap.showErrors','ngActivityIndicator','ncy-angular-breadcrumb',
'anguFixedHeaderTable', 'ui.utils','io.dennis.contextmenu'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a dependency issue but simply a naming issue.  Make sure your `ng-app` statement is correct in your HTML. By the looks of it your statement is probably `ng-app="App"` instead of `ng-app="myApp"`.